# mobile view menu issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implemented the code below, I'm facing an issue on mobile view when clicking the menu button on mobile didn't show the menu but if I didn't scroll down the menu works,
how can i fix this issue on mobile view

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu").click(function(){
        $("nav").slideToggle(800);
        $("body").toggleClass("hidden");
    })
    
        $(window).scroll(function() {
        var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (distanceFromTop >= $('.centered-logo').height())
        {
            $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else
        {
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
    
})
```

```css
body{height: 3000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.hidden{
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

nav h1 a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;    

}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }

nav ul li:hover{
    background: #f2184f;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-bar{
    width: 100%;
    background: #202c45;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
}

.responsive-bar h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 0;
    float: left;
    color:#fff;
}
.responsive-bar h3 a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.responsive-bar h4{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background:#f2184f;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width:768px){
    nav{
        display: block !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width:768px){
    nav{ 
        display: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .responsive-bar{
          top:0;
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
    }
    nav h1{
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul{
        float: none;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1)
    }
    #full-logo{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <h1 id="full-logo"><a href="#">hola</a></h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
<div class="responsive-bar">
        <h3 class="brand"><a href="#">MyCar</a></h3>
    <h4 class="menu">Menu</h4>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I have on mobile view an issue when scroll down and click menu button nothing appear but when I was at the to when click menu will appear the menu item 
all I need is when scroll down and up the menu appears 
how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you set `overflow: hidden` to your body, while the `nav` is part of the page flow. The `nav` will always be offset relative to it's parent.

Here's an example where `overflow: hidden` is disabled:
http://jsfiddle.net/u9L50243/ (Toggle the menu and then scroll - You'll notice the navigation scrolls in to, and out of the viewport)

The easiest fix is just to apply `position: fixed` to your nav bar, in addition to the `.responsive-bar`.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebcvqds7/